# How to get value from ViewModel fromRecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin

I have an Android project in MVVM Structure. In that project, consist RecyclerView. This is my code.

1.MyViewModel.kt

```
class MyViewModel(context: Application, val myRepository: MyRepository) : AndroidViewModel(context), Observable{

    ... other code ...
    val listUri: MutableLiveData<MutableList<Uri>> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<MutableList<Uri>>().apply {
            value = mutableListOf()
        }
    }
    ... other code ...

}
```

2.MyAdapter.kt

```
class MyAdapter(var items: MutableList<Uri>, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

var listItems: ArrayList<Uri> = items as ArrayList<Uri>

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.pod_list_item, parent, false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.imageIcon.setImageURI(listItems[position])

    holder.deleteIcon.setOnClickListener {
        val viewModel: MyViewModel? = null
        ....THIS PART....
        viewModel?.listUri?.value.removeAt(position) 
        ....UNTIL THIS PART....     
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return editedItems.size
}
}


class ViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    var imageIcon = view.icon_image
    var deleteIcon = view.icon_delete
}
```

When user click the delete icon in the recyclerview item, the application suppose to **delete** the selected value of `MutableLiveData<MutableList<Uri>>` in `MyViewModel` which name `listUri`.

In my marked code above, when i debug the code, it return **null** value, even though the variable listUri in ViewModel have value.
So i think, my way to access the value of ViewModel from Adapter is wrong.

How to access value of ViewModel from the adapter and then manipulate it?

If can't do that, any suggestion would be nice.

Comment: I think, i don't need to post the code from my Fragment class, because i define my adapter from my fragment class in the most common way `recyclerView.adapter = PodAdapter(podList,context!!.applicationContext)`

Answer (score -1):

you can access your ViewModel from the context which you are getting into the adapter.

Comment: How to do that? i try `context.viewModel.listUri.value` and it give me error

Answer (score -1):

I guess instead of passing the context in the constructor, pass the ViewModel instead:

```
class MyAdapter(var items: MutableList<Uri>, val viewModel: MyViewModel) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>()
```

Then instead of:

```
holder.deleteIcon.setOnClickListener {
    val viewModel: MyViewModel? = null
    ....THIS PART....
    viewModel?.listUri?.value.removeAt(position) 
    ....UNTIL THIS PART....     
}
```

You can do:

```
holder.deleteIcon.setOnClickListener {
    viewModel.listUri.value?.removeAt(position)     
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I don't understand the negative vote; is this a bad solution/practice? Is there a better, existing solution? Is this answer helpful?